# How do i find out if my view can be seen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

When the view changes, the colour of the UINavigationBar changes. But when the user presses the back button, I want it to change back, and it doesn't. How can i find out when the user goes back to the original page, so it will change back to the regular colour again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Comment: You are tagging every single of your questions with xcode, although none of them is related to it. Please consider better tagging, as your question might be not only relevant for you but for other users too. Also the xcode-tag is suffering on white-noise, as too many question that should be tagged cocoa or cocao-touch pollute.

Answer (score 1):

You can code in `viewWillDisappear` with a bool variable which checks you are going forward or backward .

When you go forward (means push or presentModelViewController) then set the BOOL as YES oterwise it is NO.

and keep track in `viewWillDissappear`.